# Why the core dumps?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, coredump

It works without bubble sort part. But when I put the bubble sort i, it says that the core dumped. I can't find the mistake so I hope someone can help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define lim 2000

int main()
{
    int a[lim],i,j,t;
    FILE *pf;

    pf=fopen("ulaz.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        fscanf(pf,"%d",&a[i]);
    }

    fclose(pf);

    for(i=lim-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[i-1])
            {
                t=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i-1];
                a[i-1]=a[i];
            }
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the most apparent mistake is the absence of indentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(j=1;j<=i;i++)
```

should be

```
for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
```

otherwise i goes above lim-1  at the first iteration of the inner loop